# What purpose does the object variable assignment serve here?

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

@ref `prototype.js`

I have seen this Prototype.js ajax syntax used everywhere. However I have not been able to figure out what role `ajaxCall` plays here.  It holds NO reference to the Ajax object being created. Prototype, by default creates an instance for every `new Ajax.Request` you call, so why are people using the variable assignment at all when it serves no purpose, (that I can see)?

```
var ajaxCall = new Ajax.Request(filepath, {
    onSuccess: this.requestSuccess.bind(this)
});

myObject.prototype.requestSuccess = function() {
    log: resp.status; //yea
    log: ajaxCall.status; //nea    
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSLint is saying "You're creating some objects but immediately discarding them; the only possible reason you can be doing that is that the act of creating the objects has side-effects, which is weird.".

Constructors should not have side-effects other than constructing the object. That's at least my opinion. PrototypeJS folks seem to think differently though.